# Checking for duplicate data

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, duplicates

I have a rather primitive table developed in Access DB. The table structure looks something like this (col name):

- Id (UNSIGNED INT)
- First Name (VARCHAR 255)
- Surname (VARCHAR 255)
- Address (TEXT)
- etc...

It contains > 1000 records. And i know for sure that there is duplication in data. For example:

1. There is two record referring to the same person, even the name is different.

One record might says John Doe, while others might say john Doe (notice the capitalization).

I am trying to migrate from Access DB to MySQL DB (this is easy), what i would like to know is what is the best way to remove all duplicates (in name) once i have successfully migrate it to MySQL.

also i don't really care if there is more than one record that that has same address. I just want to ensure that there is two or more names of the same person.

Should i:

- Do the migration via script? (e.g write a script to check, prior insertion)
- Do the migration to MySQL first, then do the checking later (can this checking be done using MySQL ?)
- Do the migration to MySQL first, then do the checking via script.

Comment: There is a saying among us data migration specialists... sh** out, sh** in :) However, given how primitive MS Access is; I would suggest migrating first, then using the capabilities of MySQL to filter out the duplicates. You can do this by a combination of GROUP BY and HAVING - that being said, both of these are actually available in MS, so it's really flip a coin as to where you filter it. If it's a critical database (meaning you need to retain the current DB in tact) then you should migrate first, then strip

Comment: That is a nice philosophy... noted.

Comment: Is there anything else you're expecting to have answered here? Aside from snide remarks, I can help you form SQL if you need.. Post what you have and I can actually help you in a tangible way

Comment: To be honest, i haven't actually started on anything. I just want to search for best solutions before actually doing it. An now that i think this migration process might happen again in the future, i might as well create a module that specifically does that.